# AdMob in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, admob

I'm inserting an AdMob in my application. but I have a problem about it.

when I inserted some codes about it in Eclipse, I can see an error message about "the constructor AdRequest() is not visible " in a fragment_03 and "error: Error parsing XML : unbound prefix" from "

so I attached source for the AdMob as follows.

Can you give me an advice ?

Let me know if you have any question.

Thanks

- fragment_03.java

  ```
  import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
  import com.google.ads.AdView;

  public class Fragment_03 extends Fragment {

  private AdView adView;
  private AdRequest adRequest;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_03, container, false);

      adRequest = new AdRequest();
      adView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_03_admob);
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);

      return rootView;
      }
  }
  ```
- fragment_03.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
      <com.google.android.ads.AdView
          xmlns:ads="schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_03_admob"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:adSize="BANNER"
          app:adUnitId="@string/activity_admobID"
          app:loadAdOnCreate="true"
          app:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <activity
          android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Change your layout in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.google.android.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_03_admob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/activity_admobID"
        app:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        app:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You was using a wrong namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes brother.... Once you see error parsing XML then know that your XML file was not properly structured. Besides, because you declared a namespace using ads instead of app in the first line of code google ads layout inside the fragment XML .

Answer (score -1):

You have to write root before the `findViewById`:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) root.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```