# Admob in fragment layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, fragment, admob

I want to put admob banner in bottom screen of the fargment layout. 
is this the correct way to implement it?:
here is my Fragment.Java.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import java.io.IOException;


public class PDFRenderFragment extends Fragment {

private ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
private PdfRenderer pdfRenderer;
private PdfRenderer.Page currentPage;
private ImageView image;
private Button btnPrevious;
private Button btnNext;
private AdView adView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdfrender, container, false);
    //admob
    AdView adView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Retain view references.
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    btnPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);
    btnNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

    //set buttons event
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(-1)); //previous button clicked
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(1)); //next button clicked

    int index = 0;
    // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
    if (null != savedInstanceState) {
        index = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_page", 0);
    }
    showPage(index);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        openRenderer(activity);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Fragment", "Error occurred!");
        Log.e("Fragment", e.getMessage());
        activity.finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        closeRenderer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (null != currentPage) {
        outState.putInt("current_page", currentPage.getIndex());
    }
}

/**
 * Create a PDF renderer
 * @param activity
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void openRenderer(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    // Reading a PDF file from the assets directory.
    fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd("regulasi_nikah.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();

    // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
    pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
}

/**
 * Closes PdfRenderer and related resources.
 */
private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
    if (null != currentPage) {
        currentPage.close();
    }
    pdfRenderer.close();
    fileDescriptor.close();
}

/**
 * Shows the specified page of PDF file to screen
 * @param index The page index.
 */
private void showPage(int index) {
    if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
        return;
    }
    // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
    if (null != currentPage) {
        currentPage.close();
    }
    //open a specific page in PDF file
    currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
    // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentPage.getWidth(),    currentPage.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
    currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
    // showing bitmap to an imageview
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    updateUIData();
}

/**
 * Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
 */
private void updateUIData() {
    int index = currentPage.getIndex();
    int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
    btnPrevious.setEnabled(0 != index);
    btnNext.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
    getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name, index + 1, pageCount));
}

private View.OnClickListener onActionListener(final int i) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (i < 0) {//go to previous page
                showPage(currentPage.getIndex() - 1);
            } else {
                showPage(currentPage.getIndex() + 1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

}

and layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/previous"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

it's actually work when i run it without admob script, but when i put some script to show banner, it crushed.

i already followed this link:
[AdMob in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512446/admob-in-a-fragment)
and this link:
[AdMob in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512446/admob-in-a-fragment)
but no luck, please suggest me the correct way to fix my problem, thanks.

Here ini my logcat

```
                10-03 14:52:02.573 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7f7d11f000)
            10-03 14:52:02.573 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7f7b893000 initialize window=0x7f7d11f010, title=com.regulasi.nikah/com.regulasi.nikah.MainActivity
            10-03 14:52:02.579 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
            10-03 14:52:02.579 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
            10-03 14:52:02.582 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/OpenGLRenderer: Created EGL context (0x7f76e95780)
            10-03 14:52:02.584 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/OpenGLRenderer: Get enable program binary service property (1)
            10-03 14:52:02.584 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
            10-03 14:52:02.585 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getFileDescriptor
            10-03 14:52:02.587 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapLen
            10-03 14:52:02.587 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapArray
            10-03 14:52:02.589 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryLen
            10-03 14:52:02.589 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 172384, program map length is 152.
            10-03 14:52:02.590 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 38, and path is /dev/ashmemd.
            10-03 14:52:02.590 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(38).
            10-03 14:52:02.594 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
            10-03 14:52:02.594 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f86803a V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-1080,1920} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@66c3489 controlFlags=#104
            10-03 14:52:02.601 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program cache from 0x7f80b99bc8, size = 3
            10-03 14:52:02.603 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000000000000)
            10-03 14:52:02.604 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000000000001)
            10-03 14:52:02.605 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000800000003)
            10-03 14:52:02.606 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7f7d11f000,api=1)
            10-03 14:52:02.606 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
            10-03 14:52:02.608 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
            10-03 14:52:02.643 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 4 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 453, 202
            10-03 14:52:02.653 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f76ea2fa0), client(33), share_fd(41)
            10-03 14:52:02.653 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f76ea2fa0) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
            10-03 14:52:02.658 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache save to disk, size = 3
            10-03 14:52:02.671 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f76ea3040), client(33), share_fd(43)
            10-03 14:52:02.671 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f76ea3040) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
            10-03 14:52:06.766 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f76ea30e0), client(33), share_fd(45)
            10-03 14:52:06.766 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f76ea30e0) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
            10-03 14:52:06.780 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f76ea3180), client(33), share_fd(47)
            10-03 14:52:06.780 14666-14763/com.regulasi.nikah D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f76ea3180) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
            10-03 14:52:06.838 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/ViewRootImpl: doProcessInputEvents ViewRoot{f39924 com.regulasi.nikah/com.regulasi.nikah.MainActivity,ident = 0}
            10-03 14:52:06.838 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/View: Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{ebe6edb VFED..C.. ...P.... 45,1407-1035,1647 #7f0c005b app:id/btn_render}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=491.50323, y[0]=154.14941, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=4784136, downTime=4784041, deviceId=7, source=0x1002 }
            10-03 14:52:06.838 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah V/SettingsInterface: invalidate [system]: current 9 != cached 0
            10-03 14:52:06.922 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err: java.io.IOException: cannot create document. Error: 3
            10-03 14:52:06.923 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeCreate(Native Method)
            10-03 14:52:06.923 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.<init>(PdfRenderer.java:153)
            10-03 14:52:06.923 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at com.regulasi.nikah.PDFRenderFragment.openRenderer(PDFRenderFragment.java:105)
            10-03 14:52:06.923 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at com.regulasi.nikah.PDFRenderFragment.onAttach(PDFRenderFragment.java:68)
            10-03 14:52:06.923 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1165)
            10-03 14:52:06.923 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1019)
            10-03 14:52:06.923 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:779)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:819)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:660)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/Fragment: Error occurred!
            10-03 14:52:06.924 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah E/Fragment: cannot create document. Error: 3
            10-03 14:52:07.046 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
                                                                                         MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
                                                                                         EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
                                                                                         bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
                                                                                         MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
                                                                                         FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
                                                                                         cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
                                                                                         LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
                                                                                         dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
                                                                                         sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
                                                                                         URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
                                                                                         qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
                                                                                         gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
                                                                                         VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
                                                                                         A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
                                                                                         4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
                                                                                         zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
                                                                                         yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
                                                                                         KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
                                                                                         Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
                                                                                         MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
            10-03 14:52:07.239 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
            10-03 14:52:07.240 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
            10-03 14:52:07.318 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah D/AppStreamingHelper: Creating delegate
            10-03 14:52:07.336 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:5
            10-03 14:52:07.336 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite, version >= 5
            10-03 14:52:07.353 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 53.0.2785.124 (code 278512450)
            10-03 14:52:07.469 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
            10-03 14:52:07.470 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-adpcm-ms
            10-03 14:52:07.471 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-adpcm-dvi-ima
            10-03 14:52:07.497 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ape
            10-03 14:52:07.504 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/alac
            10-03 14:52:07.510 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ac3
            10-03 14:52:07.526 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
            10-03 14:52:07.527 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
            10-03 14:52:07.532 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/eac3
            10-03 14:52:07.532 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
            10-03 14:52:07.533 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
            10-03 14:52:07.542 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah V/SettingsInterface: invalidate [global]: current 58 != cached 0
            10-03 14:52:07.550 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/eac3-joc
            10-03 14:52:07.557 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 4 ms (timestamps 4851-4855)
            10-03 14:52:07.557 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "53.0.2785.124", actual native library version number "53.0.2785.124"
            10-03 14:52:07.564 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-adpcm-ms
            10-03 14:52:07.571 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-adpcm-dvi-ima
            10-03 14:52:07.580 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {42643dd}
            10-03 14:52:07.581 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "53.0.2785.124", actual native library version number "53.0.2785.124"
            10-03 14:52:07.581 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(151)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
            10-03 14:52:07.589 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
            10-03 14:52:07.601 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
            10-03 14:52:07.604 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
            10-03 14:52:07.609 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
            10-03 14:52:07.609 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx3
            10-03 14:52:07.621 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/xvid
            10-03 14:52:07.625 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/flv1
            10-03 14:52:07.675 14666-14870/com.regulasi.nikah I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
            10-03 14:52:07.694 14666-14901/com.regulasi.nikah W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
            10-03 14:52:07.750 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/MPlugin: createInstance(): Begin = 4785050
            10-03 14:52:07.750 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/MPlugin: create Instance (two parameters) with : com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
            10-03 14:52:07.750 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/MPlugin: Clazz exists on mapping table : false
            10-03 14:52:07.750 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
            10-03 14:52:07.751 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/MPlugin: createInstance(): End = 4785050
            10-03 14:52:07.781 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/Ads: Starting ad request.
            10-03 14:52:07.782 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = android_id , value = 1177a1e1413c287e
            10-03 14:52:07.783 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("C2FBF888B5328956E3E9059A56E686D8") to get test ads on this device.
            10-03 14:52:07.787 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/Ads: Getting webview cookie from CookieManager.
            10-03 14:52:07.815 14666-14907/com.regulasi.nikah D/Ads: AdLoaderBackgroundTask started.
            10-03 14:52:07.816 14666-14871/com.regulasi.nikah D/Ads: Fetching ad response from remote ad request service.
            10-03 14:52:07.835 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
            10-03 14:52:07.835 14666-14666/com.regulasi.nikah E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.regulasi.nikah, PID: 14666
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.getPageCount()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.regulasi.nikah.PDFRenderFragment.showPage(PDFRenderFragment.java:124)
                                                                                    at com.regulasi.nikah.PDFRenderFragment.onViewCreated(PDFRenderFragment.java:61)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: can you post logcat?

Comment: i posted the logcat im my question

Comment: your admob code looks correct, its failing in showupdate method with null pointer exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.getPageCount()' on a null object reference. Check pagecount() method why it's returning null

Comment: Is there any solution?